# Add Subview to UITableView's Parent view

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview

I'm trying to add a *subview* to the parent view of a UITableView in order to have a *subview* that does not move when the UITableView is scrolled.
When I add the *subview* to the UITableView it moves with the table on user scrolling action.

So far, my scenario is that I have 3 UINavigationControllers on a UITabBarController.
Each has a UITableViewController.
I would like to add a subview to the screen of the individual controllers. However, I don't want the new subview to be added to the entire application like this:

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:newView];
```

When I push a new controller to the stack or pop one, I would like the *subview* to move and disappear with the UITableView it's on top of. Keeping the fact that when the user scrolls the UITableView, the new *subview* sits at its position without moving.
So that the UITableView and the new *subview* are on the same level.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of approaches:

First, to add a view to a table view that stays when the user scrolls, if your table only has one section, you can add a header for that section. For example, this adds a plain blue `UIView` as a header to the tableview:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 50)];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    return view;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 50;
}
```

Second, if you have more than one section, though, that trick doesn't work, and you'll want to use a `UIViewController` instead of a `UITableViewController`, add you header to the top of that controller's view and add a tableview to the bottom of that view. You'll want to make sure you set up (a) an `IBOutlet` for the tableview (generally to a property called `tableView`, to avoid confusion); and (b) specify the view controller as this tableview's data source and delegate.

Third, if you want this header to appear on every scene in your app, another approach (in iOS5+ apps) is to use view controller containment, create a container view that has your header, and then add your app's first scene as a child view of that view container. It's not hard, but if you're a new developer, I might discourage you from trying that. I've done it and it works well, but it's not for all people.

Fourth, if your app is using a navigation controller, you could customize the navigation bar to render your custom look and feel. It all depends upon what you're trying to accomplish with the header.

Comment: The third option was the most helpful. Even though it's tricky. It gets the job done in a perfect way.

Answer (score 1):

Add your subview to the tableview..

Implement the delegate method scrollViewDidScroll.
On scrollViewDidScroll, just set the required center of the subview you want.